# Cantor-Lebesgue's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

I have this proof of the Cantor-Lebesgue theorem that was given to me by my professor, but I don't understand a step of it.

The statement is: 
Let  $E\subset\Bbb{R}$ , measurable,  $\infty>m(E)>0$. 
Let $ f(x) =$ $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ $a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$ with $a_n,b_n$ $\in$$\Bbb{R}$
and we suppose that $\forall x\in E$, the series which define $f(x)$ converge.
Then $a_n$, $b_n$ $\to$ 0 for $n\to +\infty$.

$Proof$: 
Let $f_n(x)= a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$. 
Firstly, we see that exist $r_n$, $\theta_n$ such that $a_n = r_n\cos(\theta_n)$, $b_n=r_n\sin(\theta_n)$, in fact if $a_n=0$ and $b_n=0$, $r_n=0$ and $\theta_n=0$ are good.
If $a_n\neq 0$ or $b_n\neq 0$, we can write: 
$$a_n =\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }\cdot\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }},\quad b_n =\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }\cdot\frac{b_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }}$$
so $r_n$ = $\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }$, $\,$ $\cos(\theta_n)$ = $\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }}$, $\,$ $\sin(\theta_n)$ = $\frac{b_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2 \,+\, b_n^2 }}$ 
(it's well known that with this definition such $\theta_n$ exist).

Now, if we substitute in the definition of $f_n$ and we apply the trigonometric formula of subtraction of angles for the $\cos(x)$ function, we obtain:

$$f_n(x)=r_n\cdot\cos(nx-\theta_n)$$

Now, given that $f(x)$ converge for all $x$ in $E$, then the principal term of the series ( $f_n(x)$ ) vanished for $n$ that tends to +$\infty$.

If $a_n$ or $b_n$ don't go to zero, then $r_n$ don't go to zero, then necessarily $\cos(nx-\theta_n)$ goes to zero $\forall x \in E$, and so even $\cos^2(nx-\theta_n)$ goes to $0$.

Now, $\cos^2(nx-\theta_n) \to 0$,  $|\cos^2(nx-\theta_n)|I_E(x) \le I_E(x)$ ( $I_E(x)$ is the indicator function of E), and $I_E(x) \in L^1(E)$ imply, by dominated convergence, that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E} \cos^2(nx-\theta_n) = 0$$

We can write also $\forall n$:
$$\int_{E} \cos^2(nx-\theta_n) = \int_{E}  {1\over 2} + \int_{E} {\cos(2nx-2\theta_n)\over2}$$

Now, if we take the limit in $n$, we obtain $0 = {m(E) \over 2}$, and this is wrong because $m(E)>0$.

I have written this in my notes, but I don't understand why the second integral at the RHS vanished, because ${\cos(2nx-2\theta_n)\over2}$ should converge to $-{1\over2}$.

Maybe have I misunderstood what the professor said, or can this proof be saved?

Thanks to everyone will read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you think ${cos(2nx-2\theta_n)\over2}$ should converge to $-{1\over2}$. For typical $x$ that quantity oscillates as $n\to\infty$.

Write $$cos(2nx-2\theta_n)=\cos(2nx)\cos(2\theta_n)+\sin(2nx)\sin(2\theta_n).$$

Since the sine and cosine of $2\theta_n$ are bounded the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma (applied to $\chi_E$) shows that the integral tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the  Cantor-Lebesgue theorem that is a little more general than the one stated in the OP:

> Theorem (Cantor-Lebesgue) Let $(c_n:n\in\mathbb{Z})\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a sequence such that the  trigonometric series
> \begin{align}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{int}\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}
> converges on a set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then
> \begin{align}\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}c_n=0\tag{1}\label{TS}\end{align}

Before presenting a proof of this Theorem we make a few remarks:

1. Convergence of a series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n$ means $\lim_\limits{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{|k|\leq m}a_m$ converges.
2. The trigonometric series $\frac12a_0+\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\cos nt + b_n\sin nt$ with $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$ is of the form \eqref{zero}:
   Indeed, from
   \begin{align}
   e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x
   \end{align}
   we have that
   $$
   \sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\cos nt + b_n\sin nt=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}c_n e^{int}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\big(c_{-n}e^{-int}+c_ne^{int}\big)
   $$
   where $c_{-n}=\overline{c_n}$, and  $c_n=\frac12(a_n-ib_n)$.

***Proof of Cantor-Lebesgue's theorem:***

The result will follow from the following result:

> **Lemma:** Let $(c_n:n\in\mathbb{Z})\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a sequence such that the sequence of functions defined as $A_n(t):=c_{-n}e^{-int}+c_ne^{int}$ converges to $0$ on set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{|c_n|^2+|c_{-n}|^2}=0$.

*Proof:*

Suppose $A_n(t)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ for all $t\in F\subset[-\pi,\pi]$ where $|F|>0$. For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ define $r_n:=\sqrt{|c_n|^2+|c_{-n}|^2}$.

Suppose $\{r_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is bounded. Then, by  dominated convergence
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_F |A_n(t)|^2\,dt=0\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
From
$$|A_n(t)|^2=|c_{-n}|^2+|c_n|^2+c_{-n}\overline{c_n}e^{-2int} + c_{n}\overline{c_{-n}}e^{2int},$$
the boundedness of the $\{c_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and an application of the Riemann-Lebesgue's lemma we obtain that
\begin{align}
c_{-n}\overline{c_n}\int_F e^{-2int}\,dt+c_{n}\overline{c_{-n}}\int_F e^{2int}\,dt\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0.
\end{align}
Consequently,
$$0=\lim_n\int_F|A_n(t)|^2\,dt=|F|\lim_n r^2_n$$
Hence $r_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

If $\{r_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is not bounded, then  $r_n$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Hence,  for some $\varepsilon>0$ and some subsequence $n_k$,  $r_{n_k}\geq\varepsilon$. Define  e $B_m(t)=\frac{1}{r_m}A_m(t)$ when $m=n_k$, and $B_n(t)=0$ otherwise. Then, the sequence  $B_m$ is of the form
$$B_m(t)=c'_{-m}e^{-imt}+c_me^{imt}$$
where $r'_{m}=\sqrt{|c'_{-m}|^2+|c'_m|^2}$ forms a bounded sequence. Also, $B_m$ converges to $0$  on $F$. From case (1) it follows that $r'_m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}0$, this is in contradiction to the fact that $\limsup_mr'_m=1$. Hence $\{r_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$  must be bounded. The conclusion of the Lemma follows.