# Cantor Lebesgue theorem (Stein & Shakarchi Real Analysis problem)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, fourier-transform

I'm working on problem 2 (p.95) of Stein & Shakarchi Real Analysis textbook:

> Prove the Cantor-Lebesgue theorem: if
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n\cos nx + b_n\sin nx)$$
> converges for $x$ in a set [let's call it $E$] of positive [Lebesgue] measure (or in particular for all $x$), then $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

There is a well-known [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632896/cantor-lebesgue-theorem) of this statement for the case that $m(E) < \infty$ but it is not specified in the problem whether $E$ has finite measure. My doubt arises from the fact that if $E$ does not have finite measure, then the indicator function $\chi_E$ is not integrable, and consequently, we cannot apply the Lebesgue-Riemann theorem.

For the case $m(E) = \infty$, I was trying to apply dominated convergence theorem to a sequence $E_n \subset E$ such that $m(E_n) < \infty$ and $E_n \to E$ but I couldn't find an integrable function to dominate $E_n$.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: If $m(E)>0$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $m(E \cap [-N,N])>0$.

Comment: According to the hint provided by the book authors, you can use Egorov's theorem and conclude $A_n(x)\to 0$ *uniformly* on a set $E'$ of positive measure, slightly smaller than the original set $E$. Then we must have $r_n\to 0$, using the notation in that linked question.

Comment: Actually, once you have *uniform* convergence to $0$, then multiply $\cos(nx-\theta_n)$ on both sides of $A_n(x)=r_n\cdot\cos(nx-\theta_n)$, and the product still converges *uniformly* to $0$. Then, integrate on set $E'$. You'll then get $r_n\to 0$. This approach slightly simplifies the proof.